# Do Shiva and Vishnu know what everyone is thinking?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, mind

Do Shiva and Vishnu know what any person is thinking? Which other gods are capable of doing this?

Comment: Forget gods..If I remember correctly..even siddha yogis can read the minds of people.